# How to translate select option elements in Pyramid?

Tags: internationalization, pyramid, pylons

Until only a few minutes ago I was using this syntax to translate a select element, and then I found out that these strings (contents of the `<option/>` elements) are not being captured in the generation of the .pot file, therefore not being added to the strings for translation list.

```
<select name="sel1">
    <option i18n:translate="all">All</option>
    <option i18n:translate="new_releases">New Releases</option>
</select>
```

I am running versions Pyramid 1.5.2, Lingua 3.9, Babel 1.3

What should be the correct way to translate these `<option/>` elements?

Comment: The syntax here looks correct. Perhaps you are missing a i18n:domain earlier? Are other messages in your template extracted correctly?

Comment: i18n:domain was missing, thanks, but something is still missing. When I run the update_catalog (.pot) these translations still do not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here (after talking about this on irc) is the command used to extract messages from a template: you are using Babel's update_catalog command. This is no longer support in current versions of lingua: lingua now has its own extraction framework. That means you need to use lingua's pot-create command instead.

The [lingua documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lingua) explains why lingua no longer uses Babel, and has documentation and examples for using pot-create.